# How to rename files recursively in sequential order?

Tags: bash, shell-script, rename

I'm going crazy here. I have a lot of folders like this

```
Folder 1/
Subfolder 2/
Item.01 
Item.02
Subfolder 3/
Item.01
Item.02
```

I want to rename all files inside the folder 1, recursively and sequentially but following the current hierarchy as shown by `ls` and move them to a flat structure (all files inside a single folder).

Example:

```
Folder 1/
Item 01
Item 02
Item 03 (previously Item 01 on Subfolder 2)
Item 04 (previously Item 02 on Subfolder 2)
Item 05 (previously Item 01 on Subfolder 3)
```

Is this possible on bash? Thanks so much!

Comment: Please check your code blocks. Currently you refer to `Folder 1 ` (with trailing space) and `Folder 1`, and there are two `Item.01`s in the same `Subfolder 2`. Then, you start with `Item.01` (with a period) and move to `Item 01` (with a space). (You also refer to `Subfolder 2` and `subfolder 2`.)

Comment: I do want to rename them to just "Item 0X" in a single folder no matter what it was before. but this is just to illustrate my issue

Answer (score 2):

1. Check out how the `globstar` option in `bash` can help you:

   ```
   shopt -s globstar ; for i in ** ; do echo "$i" ; done
   ```

   That should give you a sorted list of all items in your directory tree, but it will include entries (lines) for both files and sub-directories.
2. Filter out the subdirectories:

   ```
   shopt -s globstar ; for i in ** ; do [ -f " $i" ] && echo "$i" ; done
   ```
3. Introduce a counter, and remove the current file suffixes:

   ```
   cnt=1
   shopt -s globstar
   for i in ** ; do
     [ -f "$i" ] && echo "${i%%.*}.$cnt"
     cnt=$((cnt=cnt+1))
   done
   ```
4. Replace the `echo` test statement with the `mv` of your choice:

   ```
   mv "$i" "${i%%.*}.$cnt"
   ```
5. Optionally, unset the `globstar` option after you finish:

   ```
   `shopt +s globstar`
   ```

Comment: Does this keep extensions?

Comment: @Freedo : If you want it to. Go through it step by step and learn what is going on so you can become a better unix/linux user. By the time you understand step three, if it isn't doing precisely what you want, it should be trivial to tweak it. Answers are for teaching, not for spoon-feeding.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier with `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
cd "Folder 1"
n=0; zmv -n '**/Item.<->(#qn^/)' 'Item ${(l:2::0:)$((++n))}'
```

(remove `-n` (for dry-run) when happy).

- `<->`: any sequence of decimal digits (`<x-y>` without boundary)
- `(#qn)`: for numeric sorting (so `Subfolder 10` comes *after* `Subfolder 2`).
- `^/`: exclude files of type *directory*.
- `${(l:2::0:)var}`: left-pad (and truncate if bigger) `$var` with `0`s to length 2.

A note of warning: while the `**/` glob is meant to match any level of subdirectory, including the empty level, so match files in the current directory, in `zmv` it doesn't because of the double pass it does with the pattern, once to glob and the second time as simple pattern matching to extract the capture groups (and then that second `**/Item` when pattern-matched because of the missing `/`).

A work around is to use:

```
zmv -n '(**/)Item.<->(#qn^/)' 'Item ${(l:2::0:)$((++n))}'
```

or:

```
zmv -wn '**/Item.<->(#qn^/)' 'Item ${(l:2::0:)$((++n))}'
```

but then `zmv` detects it's a recursive match and turns on the depth-first order (to be able to rename directories safely). If you don't want the depth-first order and match files in the current directory, you can use the long form of `**/` (`(*/)#`):

```
zmv -n '(*/)#Item.<->(#qn^/)' 'Item ${(l:2::0:)$((++n))}'
```

#### Example

On:

```
.
├── Subfolder 1
│   ├── Item.01
│   ├── Item.02
│   └── Subsubfolder
│       └── Item.01
├── Subfolder 10
│   ├── Item.01
│   └── Item.02
└── Subfolder 2
    ├── Item.01
    └── Item.02
```

It gives:

```
mv -- Subfolder\ 1/Item.01 Item\ 01
mv -- Subfolder\ 1/Item.02 Item\ 02
mv -- Subfolder\ 1/Subsubfolder/Item.01 Item\ 03
mv -- Subfolder\ 2/Item.01 Item\ 04
mv -- Subfolder\ 2/Item.02 Item\ 05
mv -- Subfolder\ 10/Item.01 Item\ 06
mv -- Subfolder\ 10/Item.02 Item\ 07
```